# VBA to sum values from cells between two times

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not enough familiar with VBA but unfortunately I have to make it done.

I got extract from Warehouse Management System which looks like that:
[image]

I need to count productivity of all staff according to Extract which is huge.

So I prepared xls with with 2 additional tabs. First tab contains Extract frm above. Second tab contains Count which looks like that

[image]

There is 97 rows with Start and End times (24 hrs divided for 15 minute parts)

Third tab contains Result which looks like that:

[image]

I have to create VBA macro to count productivity. Macro have to:

- Sum how many products were picked (scanned by RF gun) and store it in particular 15 minute part in tab Count.
- Sum how many 15 minute parts user was scanning product by RF guns (4 * 15 minute parts = 1h. Example: User from extract was scanning product from 03:21 to 03:43 so in tab Count I should have sum of Cases stored in 03:15 to 03:30 and 03:30 to 03:45. Hope it makes sense) according to Comodity (there are 3 comodities: Ambient, Chill, Frozen) and result have to be stored in third tab Result. If someone was scanning products in 3 different areas I should have in Result tab 3 different sums for 3 comodities.

As I said. I'm not familiar with VBA but hope you can help me. If not I will have to do it by writing filled paper based activity sheets filled by Warehouse members in to Excel and do counts by myself what gonna cost me a lot of time for 100 people.

I will appreciate so much any help.

Comment: Why do you need VBA? Simple Excel Sumifs and Countifs functions can do this for you, if I understand your needs correctly.

Comment: Or a scripting language such as python or php would do what you want in no time.

Comment: If i will be on my rest day someone else have to do this. I'm not sure about lvl of understanding formulas and excel this other person so i would rather have macro to do it automaticly after paste extract for relevant day. Secondly i can't imagine how formulas could looks like.
Unfortunately only scripting language i can use is VBA. I can't use anything else.

Comment: If you make it into a data table (select data and Ctrl+T) then Excel will automatically fill formulae down when new data is added. So you don't need to worry about your colleague's abilities etc. Then I would suggest using pivot tables to get the rest (or formulae if the data isn't too large, like <100k rows). Your table formulae would work out which start and end time bucket it is in. The pivot then groups by time bucket, user and count.

Comment: Thanks Cor. You're absolutely right with CTRL+T. I didn't think about that. Data will have around 50k rows. But there is no consistent number as extract is generated each day. I was using Pivot Tables only once. Would you please help me set up Pivot tables according to example I post above. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is the way to go.  This will kick you off with the first summary.  You will need Excel 2013 for the second one to be able to select DISTINCT counts for the 15 minute blocks.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim summaryWorksheet As Worksheet

Dim pvt1 As PivotTable

Dim firstCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set sourceWorksheet = wb.ActiveSheet


'Add two extra columns to calculate 15 minute blocks
'===================================================

'***** SET THIS TO THE TOP-LEFT CELL OF THE DATA THAT CONTAINS "Hours" LABEL
Set firstCell = sourceWorksheet.Range("A4")


'Determine the last row
lastRow = firstCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 3

'Put column captions on new columns
Cells(firstCell.Row, firstCell.Column + 4).Value = "Start"
Cells(firstCell.Row, firstCell.Column + 5).Value = "End"

'Set the formula for "Start" of 15 minute block
Range(Cells(firstCell.Row + 1, firstCell.Column + 4), Cells(lastRow, firstCell.Column + 4)).Formula = "=FLOOR(" & Cells(firstCell.Row + 1, firstCell.Column).Address(False, False) & ",TIME(0,15,0))"

'Set the formula for "End" of 15 minute block
Range(Cells(firstCell.Row + 1, firstCell.Column + 5), Cells(lastRow, firstCell.Column + 5)).Formula = "=" & Cells(firstCell.Row + 1, firstCell.Column + 4).Address(False, False) & "+""00:15"""

'Format the columns as times
Range(Cells(firstCell.Row, firstCell.Column + 4), Cells(lastRow, firstCell.Column + 5)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"


'Create a pivot table for summary by 15 minute block
'===================================================

Set summaryWorksheet = Sheets.Add
summaryWorksheet.Name = "Summary"

Set pvt1 = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                SourceData:=sourceWorksheet.Name & "!" & firstCell.CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
                                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=summaryWorksheet.Name & "!R3C1", _
                                                                                 TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                                                                                 DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15)
With pvt1.PivotFields("Start")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With pvt1.PivotFields("End")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With pvt1.PivotFields("User")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
pvt1.AddDataField pvt1.PivotFields("Cases"), "Sum of Cases", xlSum
'Change the style to be tabular
pvt1.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
'Remove unwanted subtotals
pvt1.PivotSelect "End[All;Total]", xlDataAndLabel, True
pvt1.PivotFields("End").Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
pvt1.PivotSelect "Start[All;Total]", xlDataAndLabel, True
pvt1.PivotFields("Start").Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
pvt1.PivotSelect "Start[All]", xlLabelOnly, True
Range("A3").Select

'Be a good memory citizen
Set wb = Nothing
Set sourceWorksheet = Nothing
Set summaryWorksheet = Nothing
Set pvt1 = Nothing
Set pvt2 = Nothing
Set firstCell = Nothing
```

Comment: :/ that might be a problem cause I have only Excel 2007 at my work.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements for "Sum how many 15 minute parts user was scanning product by RF guns".  If they scan 3 times in the same block (3:00-3:15), does this count as "1" or "3"?

Comment: "1" as a sum of scanned products was counted in step 1. In step 2 I need to know how long this action tooks them that is why I need count how many 15 minute parts they were doing that.